# How to validate whether a string value is a valid date or not?

Tags: node.js, momentjs, joi

I want to validate the string value which is a date is valid or not in nodejs schema object. The package I'm using for other validation is the Joi package from celebrate. Also, I don't want the type of the value to be changed to date so can't use Joi.date().

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Joi.date` if you combine it with [any.raw([enabled])](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyrawenabled):

> Outputs the original untouched value instead of the casted value
> where:
>
> enabled - if true, the original result is returned,
> otherwise the validated value. Defaults to true.
>
> Note that the raw value is only applied after validation and any
> references to the value use the validated value, not the raw value.

eg:

```
const timestampSchema = Joi.date().timestamp();
timestampSchema.validate('12376834097810'); 
// { error: null, value: Sat Mar 17 2362 04:28:17 GMT-0500 (CDT) }

const rawTimestampSchema = Joi.date().timestamp().raw();
rawTimestampSchema.validate('12376834097810'); 
// { error: null, value: '12376834097810' }
```